# Using replace in update

Tags: sql-server, replace, sql-update

I have a table with Projects, in the description field I want to replace Char(10) with '' in a lot of records.

I can replace it record by record manually like this:

```
UPDATE tblProjects
SET    Description = (SELECT Replace(Description, Char(10), ' ')
                      FROM   tblProjects
                      WHERE  ( Description LIKE '%' + Char(10) + '%' )
                             AND ProjectID = XAXD)
WHERE  ( Description LIKE '%' + Char(10) + '%' )
       AND ProjectID = XAXD
```

but would like a more generic solution like for foreach project and then have ProjectID as a variable.

Comment: the string to replace is static? or depends on project id somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just do

```
UPDATE tblProjects SET    

   Description =  Replace(Description, Char(10), ' ')

WHERE  ( Description LIKE '%' + Char(10) + '%' )
       AND ProjectID = 'XAXD'
```

You were repeating the condition in 2 places

You can also remove the `AND` part to update all projects having `char(10)`

```
UPDATE tblProjects SET    

   Description =  Replace(Description, Char(10), ' ')

WHERE  ( Description LIKE '%' + Char(10) + '%' )
```

or use parameter `@ProjectID` in place of 'XAXD'

```
Declare @ProjectID varchar(50)

SET @ProjectID = 'XAXD'
UPDATE tblProjects SET    

   Description =  Replace(Description, Char(10), ' ')

WHERE  ( Description LIKE '%' + Char(10) + '%' ) AND
       ProjectID = @ProjectID
```

Comment: I think "AND ProjectID = XAXD" is part of the "record by record manually" part :/

Comment: thanks for the help, i tried to make i more complicated than it was . you are right this does it: UPDATE tblProjects
SET    Description = Replace(Description, CHAR(10), '')
WHERE  Description LIKE '%' + CHAR(10) + '%'

Answer (score 0):

Can't you write simply

```
UPDATE tblProjects
SET    Description = Replace(Description, Char(10), ' ')
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you need the nested select. Why not just:

```
UPDATE tblProjects
SET    Description = Replace(Description, 'whatever', '')
WHERE  Description LIKE '%whatever%'
       AND ProjectID = XAXD
```

Comment: the think is for each record i have to get the description and replace Char(10 with '') and then update the same description i need to do that for each project i have 181 projectdescriptions where i need to replace Char(10) with '' in the description.

Comment: and what is `Char(10)`?? is it a static text?

Comment: UPDATE tblProjects SET Description = Replace(Description, CHAR(10), '') WHERE Description LIKE '%' + CHAR(10) + '%' Char(10) is linefeed